# Why doesn't my Kinesis Analytics Application Schema Discovery work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am sending comma-separated data to my kinesis stream, and I want my kinesis analytics app to recognize that there are two columns (both bigints). But when I populate my stream with some records and click "Discover Schema", it always gives me a schema of one column! Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I have tried many different delimiters to indicate columns, including comma, space, and comma-space, but none of these cause aws to detect my schema properly. At one point I gave up and edited the schema manually, which caused this error:

[image]

While I know that I have the option to keep the schema as a single column and use string and date-time manipulation to structure my data, I prefer not to do it this way... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

While I wasn't able to get the schema discovery tool to work, I realized that I am able to manually edit my schema and it works fine. I was getting that error because I had just populated the stream initially, and I was not continuously sending data.

Answer (score 0):

Schema Discovery required me to send data to my input kinesis stream **during** the schema discovery.  To do this for my Proof of Concept application I used the AWS CLI:

```
# emittokinesis.sh
JSON='{
    "messageId": "31c14ee7-9bde-484d-af05-03509c2c33aa",
    "myTest": "myValue"
}'
echo "$JSON"
JSONBASE64=$(echo ${JSON} | base64)

echo 'aws kinesis put-record --stream-name logstash-input-test --partition-key 1 --data "'${JSONBASE64}'"'
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name logstash-input-test --partition-key 1 --data "${JSONBASE64}"
```

I clicked the "Run Schema Discovery" button in the AWS UI and then quickly ran my shell script in a CMD window.

Once my initial schema was discovered I could manually edit the schema but it mostly matched what I expected based on my input JSON.